# Mysterious white bar at the bottom of phone app

Tags: javascript, android, phonegap

I've developed an app but for some reason, only sometimes when I open the app, a mysterious white bar will appear at the bottom of the app. My only guess is that it's the status bar.

I'm using PhoneGap so my app is built from HTML and JavaScript code with a config.xml file.

It also seems to be pushing my canvas up because I can see it's gotten a bit smaller. Here's a picture with and without:

[image]

So, as you can see, sometimes when I open the app I will get the left side with the white bar, other times I get the right side. It seems to just be random.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the CSS of your app using chrome devtools. Inspect the white area and you will likely find some CSS that causes the margin.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/

Comment: When testing on chrome, it would never ever display this. Its only now ive packaged it into a apk and downloaded it on my android phone that its appearing. Which leads me to believe its not css, rather something to do with the actual app config